# I wanna use python-shell with json data but there are some problems in python module

Tags: python, json, node.js, npm

I'm beginner of computer science.
I want to know how control JSON data in python

In nodeJS server, execute python module like this

```
const data = {"uid":"XZsGi9A93NNH4fRYYI5a2Wk4Hfm1","lat":"37.5916983","lng":"127.01206040000001"};
pythonShell.run('/python/test.py',options,(err,results)=>{
if(err){
    res.send("Error : ", err);
}else{
    console.log(results);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
}
})
```

and this is test.py

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

And results are like this

```
{ uid: 'XZsGi9A93NNH4fRYYI5a2Wk4Hfm1',
lat: '37.591696899999995',
lng: '127.0120884' }
```

As you see uid, lat, lng are not "uid", "lat", "lng", so I can't use this data to dict in python...

How I can controll json data in python???
Or how to commuicate nodejs and python with json data?

Comment: You are not using `data` in your JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "control" json in python:

```
import json

#data is your json in a dict
data = {...}

#To print, store etc CONVERT json into String
json.dumps(data)

#To read json in string, your call JSON.stringify(results) converts json to string
data = json.loads(input) #input = sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `run` method of the *python-shell* module, which is more appropriate for launching a script with arguments than for passing JSON data.

*python-shell* provides the `send` method for easier data exchange with the python script.

Here is an example of use, inspired from python-shell [tests](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/tree/master/test):

server.js

```
const PythonShell = require('python-shell');
const pyshell = new PythonShell('/python/test.py');

const data = {"uid":"XZsGi9A93NNH4fRYYI5a2Wk4Hfm1","lat":"37.5916983","lng":"127.01206040000001"};

pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(data), { mode: 'json' });

pyshell.on('message', results => {
  console.log(results);
  res.send(results);
});

pyshell.end(err => {
  if (err) res.send("Error : ", err);
});
```

test.py

```
import sys, json

for line in sys.stdin:
  print json.dumps(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import sys

print(json.loads(sys.argv[1]))
```

That is because you are just printing the input string